# How to Resove Circular Dependency in Java?

Tags: java, class, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I have 3 classes namely x, y and z. x calls y's function which calls z's method and immediately after the method gets executed in the same method i have to call x's function. This in turn results in an endless circular dependency while doing dependency injection.

How to resolve this issue ? Any way out of this ?

EventService class (class X)

```
    private void callHandlers(ApplicationEvent event) {
            ChecklistEventHandler handler = new ChecklistEventHandler();
            handler.handle(event); // here class Y is getting called.
    }

    public void createEvent(String type, String key, String creator, Map<String, Object> data) {
        AccountInfo accountInfo = (AccountInfo) Http.Context.current().args.get(GtConstants.ACCOUNT_INFO);
        String eventData = JacksonUtil.toString(data);
        ApplicationEvent event = new ApplicationEvent(accountInfo.getSchemaName(), type, key, creator, eventData);
        repository.save(event);
        scheduleForProcessing(event,accountInfo);
    }
```

ChecklistEventHandler class (class Y)

```
 public void handle(ApplicationEvent event) {
    ChecklistCriteria checklistCriteria = new ChecklistCriteria();
    checklistCriteria.setEventType(event.getType());
    checklistCriteria.setArchived(false);
    taskManagementService.createChecklistInstancesAndTask(event, checklistCriteria); // here class Z is getting called.
 }
```

TaskManagementService class (class Z)

```
 public void createChecklistInstancesAndTask(ApplicationEvent event, ChecklistCriteria checklistCriteria) {
    List<Checklist> checkListCollection = getChecklistCollectionBasedOnEvent(checklistCriteria.getEventType(),
            checklistCriteria.getArchived(),
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    createChecklistInstancesAndTask(event, checkListCollection, now); 
      //here i am calling EventService class (class X)            eventService.createEvent(TaskConstants.EventType.COMPLETE_CHECKLIST_INSTANCE,
String.valueOf(checklistInstance.getId()),   TaskConstants.EventCreator.TASK_STATUS_UPDATOR, taskMap);
}
```

Hope this clears your doubts. Now how can i redesign this without replacing X and Y class functions. Class z can be fiddled with.

Comment: Show the exact code so that we understand where your flaw is.

Comment: Rearrange your code so that you don't have a circular dependency anymore. Having a circular dependency is a sign that something is wrong in your design, and that the coupling between your classes is too tight.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire done.

Comment: @Jesper how to loosen the coupling. Can you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I miss when `callHandlers` is invoked. Where does your endless loop start?

Comment: @SouravBebarta You're using an event-based mechanism. For that, I would strongly recommend using an eventbus tool that can identify and help you resolve these conflicts. Out of my head, I think about Guava's EventBus, or the projects RxJava or RxAndroid...

Comment: @M.leRutte i have clearly mentioned in comments how from class x's method class y's method is called and from there class z's method is called which again eventually call's class x's method. So we reached where we had started from and hence the endless loop.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire what's an eventbus tool . i didn't get that and how can it help me to get rid of the circular dependency without the called out class X 's or class Y's functions. I am allowed to fiddle only with class z's functions in whichever manner i can.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your circular dependency, you need to define a terminating condition. Ask yourself what condition needs to be met in order for your code to start executing on a path other than the recursive one you have defined. So

```
private void A(){ 
     B()    
}

private void B(){
     C();
}

private void C(){
     if(conditionD){
          D();
     }else{
          A();
     }
}
```

Comment: This answer may solve infinite recursion, but that's not what the OP's problem is.

Comment: @Chris Phillips I always need to call function A from from function C. There is no condition D as such in my requirement.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That's true.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'm not seeing how this isn't infinite recursion.

Comment: Whether it's infinite recursion or not, adding a terminating condition still doesn't solved the stated problem. There is still a circular dependency even when you have a terminating condition.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips this is infinite recursion. But it's not my problem exactly. Kindly go through my question again.

Comment: @SouravBebarta how is this infinite recursion? All I see in your code is a circular dependency. Class X depends on class Y which depends on class Z which depends on class X. But method X.a calls Y.b which calls Z.c which calls X.d (not X.a).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException maybe i didn't make myself clear.i meant @ Chris Phillips code is example of infinite recursion in event that the conditionD fails and else part gets executed.